# Get events in the fired order

Tags: c#

Application A issues command "DoWork" to Application B. Application B is remoting server. B fires events WorkStarted and WorkCompleted asynchronously(using Thread Pool) . Sometimes A gets WorkCompleted event before WorkStarted..
Is there any pattern or technique available to enure that Application A gets WorkStarted event before WorkCompleted event?

Comment: Please write out what "using TP" means, it isn't self-evident.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Edited my post. TP = ThreadPool

Answer (score 1):

Synchronize each event, e.g., have each one just do a `SynchronizationContext.Post` to a context that does synchronization, such as a UI context.